# Boolean TRUE converted to string "1" when testing GraphQL request with Codeception

Tags: php, wordpress, graphql, codeception

I have a Wordpress website with the WPGraphQL plugin installed and running some tests with Codeception to test the GraphQL queries. For a bit more context, I am using Codeception's REST module and loading Wordpress in the tests with [wp-browser](https://github.com/lucatume/wp-browser).

The following test to register a user is failing:

```
class RegisterCest { 

   public function seeCanRegister( ApiTester $I ) {

      $I->send( "POST", "https://example.com/graphql", [
         "query" => '
            mutation registerUser( $input: RegisterUserInput! ) {
               registerUser( input: $input ) {
                  user {
                     username
                     email
                     addressMain
                     addressSec
                     adminArea
                     country
                     city
                     firstName
                     lastName
                     postalCode
                  }
               }
            }         
         ',
         "variables" => [
            "input" => [
               "clientMutationId" => "registerUser",
               "firstName" => "John",
               "lastName" => "Smith",
               "username" => "user@example.com",
               "email" => "user@example.com",
               "password" => "example",
               "addressMain" => "Fake Street",
               "addressSec" => "Apt #1",
               "adminArea" => "New York",
               "country" => "US",
               "city" => "New York",
               "postalCode" => 00000,
               "planSlug" => null,
               "subscribeToNewsletter" => true
            ]
         ]
      ]);

      $I->seeResponseCodeIs( 200 );
      $I->dontSeeResponseJsonMatchesJsonPath( "$.errors" );   

   }

}
```

The test fails because I get the following error in the response:

> Expected type Boolean at value.subscribeToNewsletter; Boolean cannot
> represent a non boolean value: 1"

Basically, what seems to happen is that the boolean `true` set as the value for `subscribeToNewsletter` is transformed into the string `"1"` before the query is executed, which causes the query to be invalid because in the GraphQL schema it is specified that `subscribeToNewsletter` is expected to be a boolean.

**I do not get this error when running the query in the app; it's only coming up in this test**. Can anyone think of a reason why?

Comment: Make sure to POST your variables with Content-Type: application/json

Comment: @ArvinJasonCabrera Yep, that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Arvin Jason Cabrera in the comments, the problem was I was not setting the Content-Type to application/json. In my case, I simply had to add the following line

```
$I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

before sending the request.